# Upload an image using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I want to upload an image in Zend-framework.

In Application_Form_Test.php I write following code....

```
uploadImage = new Zend_Form_Element_File('uploadImage');
$uploadImage->setLabel("Upload Image ")
            ->setRequired(true)               
            ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpeg,png')
            ->getValidator('Extension')->setMessage('This file type is not supportted.');
```

In the testAction() I write following code.....

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$upload->addValidator('Size', false, 52428800, 'image');
$upload->setDestination('uploads');
$files = $upload->getFileInfo();
foreach ($files as $file => $info) {
    if ($upload->isValid($file)) {
         $upload->receive($file);
    }
}
```

Code is running successfully But I am not getting that image to the destination folder?

What may be the problem....?
Please help me.....

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the getFileInfo() method is supposed to actually execute the file upload. I believe that in your controller action, you have to either call the getValues() method on the form object, or call the receiveFile() method on the form element.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file for the documentation examples.

Answer (score 0):

An additional note: if you look in `Zend_Form_Element_File->receive()`, you will see that isValid() is called, so there's no need to clutter your controller with it. Here's what I do:

```
if ($upload->receive()) {
    if ($upload->getFileName() && !file_exists($upload->getFileName())) {
        throw new Exception('The upload should have worked, but somehow did not!');
}
} else {
    throw new Exception(implode(PHP_EOL, $upload->getErrors()) . implode(PHP_EOL, $upload->getErrorMessages()));
}
```